# Is possible somehow explore youtube videos by hashtag?

Tags: youtube, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have been looking at the YouTube API and I am wondering if it is possible somehow search  YouTube videos by hashtags e.g.

I want explore YouTube video for hashtag `#funny`

I have read YouTube API documentation but I haven't found anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Search: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list)

> Returns a collection of search results that match the query parameters specified in the API request. By default, a search result set identifies matching video, channel, and playlist resources, but you can also configure queries to only retrieve a specific type of resource.

In my experience this is a full text search on title and description of the video so assuming your hash tags are in the description you should be able to search on them.

**Request**

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=25&q=%23funny&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

**Response**

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
 "etag": "\"RmznBCICv9YtgWaaa_nWDIH1_GM/wR5yPzOxAnu-87xJGtSkLXz_78Q\"",
 "nextPageToken": "CBkQAA",
 "regionCode": "DK",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1000000,
  "resultsPerPage": 25
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"RmznBCICv9YtgWaaa_nWDIH1_GM/IByts9zZTVNkc5EfbIDTKpE6pf8\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "DODLEX4zzLQ"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2017-06-17T10:03:47.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCKy3MG7_If9KlVuvw3rPMfw",
    "title": "WATCH and TRY TO STOP LAUGHING - Super FUNNY VIDEOS compilation",
    "description": "Can you hold your laugh while watching these clips? :) Mix of best and funniest animal & human fails. We bet you will lose this laugh challenge. Anyways, what is your favorite clip? :) Hope...",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/DODLEX4zzLQ/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/DODLEX4zzLQ/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/DODLEX4zzLQ/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Tiger Productions",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  },
```

This is the video it returned [WATCH and TRY TO STOP LAUGHING - Super FUNNY VIDEOS compilation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DODLEX4zzLQ) #funny is in the description.

You can try it yourself here [Google Apis Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=snippet&maxResults=25&q=%2523funny&_h=1&)

Comment: Hows that you can test it out yourself.