# How to get a random video by hashtag using YouTube Java API

Tags: java, random, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I need a way of get a random YouTube video by hashtag. As an example I would like a random video for the tag `#meme`.

How can I do with with the YouTube Data API? (Java)

Here is what I tried so far:

1. I went through the api and examples at YouTube dev site. http://www.youtube.com/dev/ no luck finding the correct API or a way of doing it there.
2. I found http://randomyoutubevideo.net/ from a Google search, but they only offer an API from THEM to use in between me and YouTube. This gives me hope that it IS actually possible to do this.

Comment: The closest thing you will get is https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list but thats not going to work on a hashtag.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49670740/is-possible-somehow-explore-youtube-videos-by-hashtag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably use the [`search:list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) endpoint from the YouTube Data API V3 like so:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=25&q=%23funny&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Where `%23` is the literal for a hashtag (`#`)

Comment: okay, is there any argument that is also looking for the length of the video?

Comment: `videoDuration` should work, though it only allows for categorical values (short, medium, long). You must also set the `type` to video